# Failed to lookup view "index.ejs" in views directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have the following code in my express app (app.js file):

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

app.listen(8080);
```

And the following dependencies:

```
"ejs": "^2.6.1",
"express": "^4.16.3",
"request": "^2.87.0"
```

And this is my folder structure:

```
myapp
   app.js
   package.json
   views
      index.ejs
   node_modules
      [all node files]
```

But when I run the app, it shows this error:

```
Failed to lookup view "index.ejs" in views directory "mylocaldirectory/myapp/views"
```

If it would help here are the other error messages:

```
  at Function.render (/mylocaldirectory/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (/mylocaldirectory/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
    at //mylocaldirectory/myapp/app.js:11:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/mylocaldirectory/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/mylocaldirectory/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/mylocaldirectory/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/mylocaldirectory/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /mylocaldirectory/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/mylocaldirectory/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/mylocaldirectory/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

I get no error if I just use `res.send("SOME TEXT")` but when I try to render an ejs file, it doesn't. What's the issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to set your `view`  directory and your `viewengine` before requesting any of your view files.

Hence you need to add the below lines, before your `app.get`

```
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

And your `res.render('index.ejs');` should be changed as,

```
res.render('index');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this but it still says: Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "./views"

Comment: What happens when you try, `app.set('views', './myapp/views');` ?

Comment: Same, Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "./myapp/views"

Comment: My bad, I found the error already. It's because my saved file is actually index.ejs.html for some reason. Corrected it now.

Comment: try: path.join(__dirname, 'views')

Answer (score 4):

First you have to tell express what view engine to use by setting

`javascript
// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`

And when referring to a view you should leave out the extension. So instead of `res.render('index.ejs');` use `res.render('index');`.

Setting up the view folder is not required since you're using the default view folder `views` to store your view files.

Answer (score 4):

This issue basically comes when your ejs views engine unable to find file or folder.
So do following checks:

1.check directory name. it should be 'views' not 'view'.

2.check file under directory having correct file extension or not? it should be `.ejs` only not others like `.html` or `.json` etc.

3.tell express that i am going to use ejs view engine by using below code:

```
 app.set('view engine','ejs');
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you set up the views folder?

```
app.set('views', './views')
```

Answer (score 3):

I used this:

```js
const express = require("express");
const server = express();
const path = require("path");

server.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
server.set("view engine", "ejs");
server.use(express.static("public"));

server.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, 'app.set' function is unable to find 'views' folder.
So use following...

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
```

or you can do as following

```
const path = require('path')
//path is inbuilt module in nodejs, so don't need to install it.

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
```

both methods are same.
__dirname will concatenate absolute path to 'views' folder.

(note: Notice that . is should not be there while concatenating with absolute directory path.
So don't use './views' after __dirname, use '/views' only)

Answer (score 1):

The [express guide on template engines](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) talks about setting up the 'views' and the 'view engine'. I also found it important / interesting to talk about redundancy. All detailed below.

### Setting up 'views'

By default, it looks for the template files (be them .ejs, .pug, etc.) on a subfolder called "views".
So you can either set up this subfolder called "views" with your .ejs files in it or set this 'views' folder to any that you wish.
Using `app.set('views', './')`, for example, sets the 'views' folder to be the current folder (i.e. no subfolders needed).

### Setting up 'view engine'

The guide also points out that you can either specify the engine (ejs, pug, etc.) or specify the file extension when using, for example, `res.render(<filename>)`.

### Redundancy

So, a very redundant way of doing things is (before any routing)

```
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get("/", function(req,res) {
  res.render("index.ejs");
});
```

with a folder structure like

```
myapp
   app.js
   package.json
   views
      index.ejs
   node_modules
      [all node files]
```

Since you have a folder called "views" with your .ejs files in the same level of your app.js file, you can omit the `app.set('views', './views')` command.

Since you call `res.render` with the file extension, you can omit the `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')` command.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have only css files in public folder .other folders can be outside the public folder.

Comment: Is this really the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

try this it worked for me.

```
// view engine setup
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');    
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

Comment: If this solution doesn't work for you, just give me a heads up with some more info on why, and I'll do my best to help you out

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error.
By doing below steps, I got the Result.

1. Create a views folder.
2. Move your home.ejs file into the views folder then Execute.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35471036)

Answer (score -1):

Make Sure you have corrected file name with ejs extension.
Make Sure you have corrected folder name views.
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

It will work properly

Answer (score -3):

```
app.set('views', './View'); //./View(You already created folder)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
res.render('index', { kindDay: day });
```

index is my EJS file.
kindDay is EJS file-created key.