# Do not include index.ejs file in dist folder

Tags: node.js, express

### tsconfig.json

```sh
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    "outDir": "./dist",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

### error

> {"message":"Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/var/www/tutor/dist/views"","code":50000}

### command

> tsc && node dist/app.js -> build dist folder

src > views > index.ejs

Do not include index.ejs file in dist folder.

Comment: Can you show us your `tsconfig.json` ?

Comment: @eol yes upload this.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question, but if you're wondering why tsc doesn't copy the .ejs files to the dist folder: you have to do that manually. Typescript handles only its own source files, not resource files.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript compiler does not copy the other types of files the project needs to run, such as the EJS view templates. To accomplish this, create a build script that copies all the other files to the dist folder.

```
npm install --save-dev ts-node shelljs @types/shelljs
```

Make a new folder in the root of the project named scripts. Create a file in the tools folder named copy-assets.ts. Copy the following code into this file.

```
import * as shell from "shelljs";

// Copy all the view templates
shell.cp( "-R", "src/views", "dist/" );
```

Update the scripts in package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "ts-node scripts/copy-assets",
    // ..rest
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue.
It works by setting the dir .

For me, /views folder is inside the /src .

```
app.set("views", "./src/views");
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Duplicated Issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51231280/3269542