# I'm a beginner to Node Js. When I am trying to access the index.ejs file I am getting the following error Error:

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

```
import express from "express"
const app=express()
const port =3000;


app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("index.ejs", {Datatype:"a weekday", 
    advice: "it's a weekday, so work hard",
});
})


app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server is running on ${port}`)
})
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index.ejs" in views directory "D:\Udemy\Node js\EJS\views"
    at Function.render (D:\Udemy\Node js\EJS\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:597:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (D:\Udemy\Node js\EJS\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
    at file:///D:/Udemy/Node%20js/EJS/index.js:10:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Udemy\Node js\EJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\Udemy\Node js\EJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\Udemy\Node js\EJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Udemy\Node js\EJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\Udemy\Node js\EJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (D:\Udemy\Node js\EJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (D:\Udemy\Node js\EJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
```

I want the index.ejs file to be rendered but it's showing me the error.

Comment: The error is pretty clear: you don't have an `index.ejs` file in that folder. That's really all we can tell you. Have you followed a tutorial that [explains how to set up ejs](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application) on your system?

Comment: Yes, index.ejs file is there in the view folder only. But I had it resolved. The issue was, I kepth both index.js and index.ejs in the same folder. Once I kept index.js file outside the view folder. . it's working. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a duplicate of this other Stackoverflow question:
[Failed to lookup view "index.ejs" in views directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51231256/failed-to-lookup-view-index-ejs-in-views-directory)

"You need to set your view directory and your viewengine before requesting any of your view files.

Hence you need to add the below lines, before your app.get

```
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

And your `res.render('index.ejs');`  should be changed as,

```
res.render('index');
```

Hope this helps!"

- David R